# How do I know if a BigQuery query is purning partitions or not?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am issuing a query on a BigTable table and have a WHERE clause on the partition column which I'm confident is pruning the partitions (which is good).

```sql
select *
from `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`
where dateTimeCreated >= '2021-11-27' --partition column
  and emailAddress = 'thing@example.com'
```

I'm keen to understand more about what is going on internally though. I was hoping the query plan (shown in "Execution details" in the BigQuery console) would explicitly state that its only consuming from one partition however that information doesn't seem to be available. All I see for the READ operation of stage S00 is:

```
FROM project_id.dataset_id.table_id
WHERE and(greater_or_equal($6, 1637971200.000000000), equal($30, 'thing@example.com'))
```

I know from the number of rows output from this stage that it is only retrieving from one partition however I would have hoped to see some information about this in the query plan. For a more complicated query than this its going to be really important to know which partitions are being queried,how many partitions are being queried, or at least know whether or not partition pruning is occurring.

Is this information available anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, not all details are displayed in the BigQuery console. However, you may find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#query_plan_information) useful that explains more details present in the API responses, which may include information regarding partitions.

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked, however if you remove the filter clause and put it again, you will come to know the difference in the number of bytes scanned

Comment: I never mentioned anything about bytes being scanned.

Comment: @MabelA. Thank you I shall take a look